Why doesn't this write any values?
=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IF(MID(A1,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7},1)="N","",{"S","M","T","W","T","F","S"}))

Testing on cell A1 which has NYNNYNY. Using google sheets, not excel.
